# Собрать сложный объект в FormData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formdata

Подскажите пожалуйста как собрать такой объект в Formdata?

Я собирал простой объект с текстовыми полями через formdata.append(key, value), но с таким объектом как быть с вложенными объектам и массивом фалов?

вот так принимает сервер данные http://joxi.ru/KAgn9k9iXaae82

```js
let data {
  offer: {
    comment: 'text',
    price: '50'
  },
  files: [File, File]
}
```

Comment: вложенный объект так же как и простой, а файлы отдельно через append

Comment: Можете пример написать пожалуйста, а то я видел вообще какие-то дикие конструкции

Comment: пример чего? Ты же написал, что уже _собирал простой объект с текстовыми полями через formdata.append(key, value)_ - все то же самое

Comment: то есть получится formdata.append(offer, {comment: 'text', price: '50'})?

Comment: @Grundy А с файлами получается будет выглядеть вот так formdata.append(files, [File, File])?

Comment: каждый файл отдельно: [`formData.append(name, value, filename);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

Comment: _то есть получится `formdata.append(offer, {comment: 'text', price: '50'})`?_ - а когда ты собирал простой объект с текстовыми полями ты так же писал?

Comment: _вот так принимает сервер данные_ - непонятно что это за скриншот и что на нем показано

Comment: @Grundy нет это я для наглядности подставил значение переменных, которые туда будут подставляться в цикле

Comment: ну вот делаешь точно так же

Comment: @Grundy offer, [object Object] это нормальный вид которые получает сервер? по-моему нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106286/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexey-alpatov).